How can I use 'mklink' to link 'read/write' game files to an existing directory with additional game data in it?
I recently downloaded Halo: The Master Chief Collection through PC Xbox Game Pass. The game is a collection of 6 or so games, so it's a whopping 116 GB large. Because of this, I've installed the game on an internal HDD.
The game runs fine, but it tends to use a 10 - 25 Mbps transfer rate on the HDD as I assume it needs to constantly stream assets from the HDD to the game. This causes frame rate drops at times, but I don't really mind that. My main issue is the 15 - 30 minute wait when I load up the game. It genuinely takes almost half an hour to load the main menu.
I found after some research that there are 6 hexadecimal-named files that apparently manage all the read/write processes for the game. The post I found said to create a RAM Disk of 900 MB (just enough to contain those files), backup and move the 6 files to the RAM Disk and link them using 'mklink' back to the game folder. In theory, this should allow the RAM Disk to manage the read/write processes instead of the HDD, and improve load times, right?
I created an NTFS RAM drive of 900 MB using IMDisk. I also took note of another user who managed to pull this off and improve their game speeds. Once this was done, I created a backup of the 6 supposed read/write files and moved them to the RAM drive. This where I got stuck. I don't know how to correctly use 'mklink' to link these files back to the game folder.
You see, the 6 files are located in the 'Halo- The Master Chief Collection' folder, which contains the 6 files, and another folder called 'Content,' which contains majority of the game files and is 103 GB.
So, I tried to make a symbolic link between the 6 files on the RAM drive and the existing Halo MCC directory through:
mklink /d "Z:\HaloMCCFiles" "E:\XboxGames\Halo- The Master Chief Collection"
Where E: is the HDD with the game, and Z: is the RAM Drive. I might not be able to remember which way around they were correctly, so they could've been swapped.
Either way, when I executed this command the main error I got was something along the lines of
Cannot create a file when that file already exists.
I understand that in my case the folder called 'Halo- The Master Chief Collection' cannot exist before I execute this command, as it tries to create that folder with the linked files in it. I can't exactly put the whole 103 GB on a linked folder to a 900 MB Ram disk, so I'm looking for possible workarounds.

Try using instead a junction (using the /J parameter). Note that the parameters in your example are swapped.

I suspect you actually want to link the Content directory into your RAM disk rather than the whole directory. so mklink /j "Z:\content" "E:\XboxGames\Halo- The Master Chief Collection\Content" You want the directory structure to look as identical to the main game folder structure as possible.

Mklink is a directory or file symbolic link creation tool.
You cannot create a symbolic link to multiple locations, so having a few files in one location on your fast drive, and the other files on your slow drive, and magically merge them together using mklink is not possible.
But in your case, it are specific files that you want to move.
Mklink can also be used to link to specific files.
This is what you want to use.
You are mentioning the use of a ramdrive however. This brings a problem with it, that may stop you from going after this solution.
A ramdrive is always empty when created, and loses its content the moment you turn off your computer (with the exception of hibernation)
If those 6 files need to contain data before the game loads, then the following process will have to be done:

Create RAMDRIVE
Copy the 6 files to the ramdrive
Wait for the files to have copied
Play the game.

It can be that step 3 is going to take just as long or longer as when you normally play the game with those 6 files located on your main harddisk.
If you still want to proceed with this, then do the following steps.
First, create a new folder on your HDD and move those 6 files to that new location. (this is so you can now always copy those 6 files to the RAM drive if necessary)
Create the RAMDrive, and copy the 6 files from the HDD's new location. Time this, because this will tell you if its even worth doing this or not. You will have to wait this long every single time, in addition of the loading that needs to be done when playing the game.
Now, in your game folder, create the symbolic links in the E: folder.
cd /d "E:\XboxGames\Halo- The Master Chief Collection"
mklink /j "file1.ext" "Z:\HaloMCCFiles\file1.ext"

and repeat the mklink command for all 6 files. Note that mklink uses this syntax: mklink [link] [target]
Note, the game may crash if the ramdrive is not created. Also, if you first start the game, and then create the ramdrive, its probably not gonna work. Make sure the ramdrive and the 6 files exist before starting the game.

"You cannot create a symbolic link to multiple locations" - isn't that the purpose of hard links: mklink /h? Granted, hard links wouldn't work for a RAM drive in this instance since hard links have to reside on the same volume as the target.

@JW0914 nope. You can have multiple hardlinks to the same file, but not one hardlink accessing multiple locations simultaneously.

I did have that backwards didn't I lol

@JW0914 It seems so. :) If it helps, been there, done that. xD

this is what u run in cmd after running starwind ram disk and copying the 6 files into the new D: ram drive:
cd /d "C:\XboxGames\Halo- The Master Chief Collection"
mklink "050FBB4D-16E5-42A8-945A-963D007974AA" "D:\050FBB4D-16E5-42A8-945A-963D007974AA"
mklink "050FBB4D-16E5-42A8-945A-963D007974AA.F498FA46-416D-42FC-82DE-21BF2A0E620F.xsp" "D:\050FBB4D-16E5-42A8-945A-963D007974AA.F498FA46-416D-42FC-82DE-21BF2A0E620F.xsp"
mklink "050FBB4D-16E5-42A8-945A-963D007974AA.smd" "D:\050FBB4D-16E5-42A8-945A-963D007974AA.smd"
mklink "050FBB4D-16E5-42A8-945A-963D007974AA.xct" "050FBB4D-16E5-42A8-945A-963D007974AA.xct"
mklink "050FBB4D-16E5-42A8-945A-963D007974AA.xvi" "050FBB4D-16E5-42A8-945A-963D007974AA.xvi"
mklink "050FBB4D-16E5-42A8-945A-963D007974AA.xvs" "050FBB4D-16E5-42A8-945A-963D007974AA.xvs"

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
